# GameCenter Invitation Handler

Tags: objective-c, game-center, multiplayer, invite

trying to implement a multiplayer. Using the sample from [Game Center - Sending and receiving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574119/game-center-sending-and-receiving-data).

Everything seems okay, but in [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW5) there is also said about invitation handler.

```
[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {
   // Insert application-specific code here to clean up any games in progress.
   if (acceptedInvite) {
        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
    } else if (playersToInvite) {
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        request.minPlayers = 2;
        request.maxPlayers = 4;
        request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;

        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
    }
};
```

The problem is quite simple: I do not know where to add this code.

Comment: EXACT same question came to my mind ;)\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in the docs

> Your application should set the
>   invitation handler as early as
>   possible after your application is
>   launched; an appropriate place to set
>   the handler is in the completion block
>   you provided that executes after the
>   local player is authenticated.

Somewhere in your code, you should have authenticated the local player with something like this

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Insert your piece of code here
    } else {
        // Handle the error
    }
}];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: My problem. Have not read everything. Sorry for silly question.

Comment: Hello. Could you please see my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970538/how-to-accept-an-invitation-in-game-center

Answer (score 1):

My code is below, and it works very well. In the `authenticateLocalUser`, add the code below:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {  // Add for invite handler
        // Insert application-specific code here to clean up any games in progress.
        if (acceptedInvite) {
            GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] ;
            mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
            // [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
            [_delegate matchStart];
        } else if (playersToInvite) {
            GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] ;
            request.minPlayers = 2;
            request.maxPlayers = 2;
            request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;

            GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] ;
            mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
            // [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
            [_delegate matchStart];
        }
    };

    [self callDelegateOnMainThread:@selector(processGameCenterAuth:) withArg:NULL error:error];
}];
```