# Difference between Game Center's didRequestMatchWithOtherPlayers and didRequestMatchWithRecipients?

Tags: ios, game-center

What is the exact difference between those two methods in iOS 8's `GKLocalPlayerListener`?

- `GKInviteEventListener player(didRequestMatchWithRecipients:)` -- called when the local player starts a match with another player from Game Center
- `GKTurnBasedEventListener player(didRequestMatchWithOtherPlayers:)` -- initiates a match from Game Center with the requested players

Both are marked `required`, but apparently neither is mentioned in Apple's *Game Center Programming Guide*.

**UPDATE**

And futhermore what is the difference to the recepient response header? In the case of programmatic match-making, which ones of these three handlers is one supposed to implement and with what exact semantics?

- `GKMatchRequest recipientResponseHandler`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think didRequestMatchWithRecipients gets called at all anymore.  didAcceptInvite is called on the receiving device when they accept an invitation. didFindMatch is called on all devices when the Match Maker View Controller has finished. I have set breakpoints and logs in the method and started the game every way I can think of but nothing shows that didRequestMatchWithRecipients is called. To be fair - what is the point in the method: didAcceptInvite lets you get started and didFindMatch gives you a match object with all the information you need?

Comment: I have given a much better, longer answer to this at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909746/1627959